# Adding DOM elements with jquery append() appears to leak memory?

Tags: jquery, dom, memory, memory-leaks

Just met with a customer who have huge memory leak issues in their Ajax webapp. So I decided to create the following testcase to demonstrate the problem:

I have used drip / Sieve for memory profiling in the example below 
(http://home.orange.nl/jsrosman/)

The case is simple: I have the following javascript:

```
<html>
    <head>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js">
</script>    
</head>    
<script type="text/javascript">

    var lihtml = "<li class='green'>this is a test text</li>";

    function populatelist() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            $('#listparent').append(lihtml);
        }    
    }    

    function clearlist() {
        $('#listparent').empty();
        if (typeof (CollectGarbage) == "function") {
            alert('gc');
            CollectGarbage();
        }    
    } 


    /* Alternative clearlist with Remove instead of Empty(), still leaks */
    function clearlist() {
        /* test remove the parent itself instead of empty below */
        $('#listparent').remove();
        $('body').append("<ul id='listparent'>");        
        //$('#listparent').empty();
        if (typeof (CollectGarbage) == "function") {
            alert('gc');
            CollectGarbage();
        }
    }

   /* Edit!, this is the most effective way to release memory so far */
   function clearlist() {
    $('#listparent').html("");
    if (typeof (CollectGarbage) == "function") {
        alert('gc');
        CollectGarbage();
    }
}
</html>   
</script>

<body>
    <button onclick="javascript:populatelist()">Populate list</button>
    <button onclick="javascript:clearlist()">Clear list</button>
    <ul id="listparent">
        <li>kjjk</li>
    </ul>    
</body>

</html>
```

Each click on populate list appends 10000 li elements (represented as text). Clearlist calls jquery empty() which supposedly should clear the DOM subtree and make it eligible for GC.

So I run this case in sIEve and for each time I append new elements the memory usage increases, I have never seen it garbage collect or free memory. Not even when the RAM usage reaches 1.5GB and even though I try calling GC explicitly for IE.

This is the same sympton I saw at the customer who used Jquery Ajax for the List data instead of my static content obv.

Am I creating the DOM in the wrong way ? Can anybody tell me why it isn't garbage collected, I can't see any other references to the DOM elements as to why they shouldnt be garbage collected. Another weird behaviour is that sometimes in sIEve memory usage even increase when I click empty list (when jquery empty() method is being called) ?

If anybody has input I would be VERY happy.

UPDATE, I tried using $('#listparent').html("") instead which seems to release the DOM correctly, at least it is being released in sIEve. I guess that's the best solution so far though I have no explanation to why remove() and empty() doesn't seem to work. Maybe they only work for statically added elements ?

Comment: just curious, have you tried this in multiple browsers?

Comment: No sIEve only works in IE, haven't tried FFX, mostly because IE is the only used browser by the users in this system.

Comment: Actually $('#listparent').html(""); works much better than both empty() and remove() and seems to release the whole DOM. I'm speechless

Answer (score 1):

yes you could make an huge improvement doing smthg like so

```
var lihtml = "<li class='green'>this is a test text</li>",
    listring = "";

function populatelist() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            listring += lihtml;
        }    

        $('#listparent').append(listring);

    }    
...
```

limit DOM access as few as possible.

The difference is that you make 1 single append instead of 10 thousands appends. You always need to avoid DOM manipulation inside cycles

Edit:
instead of empty() your ul have you tried to remove() the ul and then suddenly re-create it?

Comment: This is a good suggestion and I tried it, the problem still remains though, it's still leaking and empty() doesn't seem to free the DOM. Seriously starting to lose faith in jquery.

Comment: I tried remove(), it still leaks but maybe slightly less than empty() which seems to increate memory rather than releasing. What is really weird is that $('#listparent').html(""); does the trick and releases the whole DOM and the RAM memory?!?

Comment: @user408346 Would you mind updating your question with this information? Also please add the solution as an answer and when you can, mark it as correct. It could be very useful to many people.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest appending to the HTML string and then adding it to the DOM:

```
function populatelist() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        //$('#listparent').append(lihtml);
        lihtml += "<li class='green'>this is a test text</li>";
    }    
}    
populateList();
$('#listparent').append(lihtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#listparent').html("");
```

works where neither empty() or remove() did. I wish I knew why. I guess it's a solution though.

/* This is the most effective way to release memory so far */

```
function clearlist() {
    $('#listparent').html("");
    if (typeof (CollectGarbage) == "function") {
        alert('gc');
        CollectGarbage();
    }
```